# Pervasive & Linux

Tags: php, windows, linux, pervasive

I'm interested in quering a Pervasive DB server running on a Windows platform from Linux.

Would anyone happen to know if this is possible, what's required and what resources there are for me to read up on it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What version of Pervasive are you using?  All versions since v8 (including v9 and v10) support a Linux client which is included with the Pervasive.SQL server engine.  V9 and V10 clients are also available for download from the Pervasive website (http://www.pervasivedb.com/Database/Products/PSQLv10/Pages/PSQLOverview.aspx).  Once you've got a client installed on the Linux machine, you can create an ODBC DSN or use the Btrieve API to access the data.

Answer (score 1):

Most database have at least a command line client to connect to database. check your brand of database to see if you have such tools. For example, Mysql has `mysql` command line client for making query to MySql database. Otherwise, another way is you might want to try setting up [ODBC with Perl](http://ww1.pervasive.com/library/docs/psql/910/sgs/sgs-21-7.html).